# How to call a jquery datetime picker in the image button placed by the textbox control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my jquery datetimepicker i want to call this jquery in the image button which is placed nearby the textbox.how should do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $( "#<%= this.txtFrom.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showmonth:true,
            autoSize: true,
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            duration: 'fast'
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my textbox and imagebutton.

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" MaxLength="10" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter From Date"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/clock_add.gif" />
```

when i click this image button that jquery should call.

Comment: datepicker supposed to do this automatic for you. check the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: @ric_bfa, why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @William Niu,  as you wish :)

Comment: Check the updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484693/how-to-call-a-jquery-datetime-picker-in-the-image-button-placed-by-the-textbox-co/7488813#7488813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            showmonth:true,
            autoSize: true,
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            duration: 'fast'
        });

        $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
          $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" MaxLength="10" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter From Date">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/clock_add.gif" />
```

Reference [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/displaying-a-datepicker-on-custom-button-click-event)

Answer (score 1):

like i say in comment:

datepicker supposed to do this automatic for you. check the documentation:

[jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger](http://datepicker%20supposed%20to%20do%20this%20automatic%20for%20you.%20check%20the%20documentation%3a%20jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Comment: Hum....I just noticed Thruimaran actually used it already...but just incorrectly....

Comment: datepicker itself create a button

Answer (score 0):

You really have two choices here, which are precisely what ric_bfa and Harsh mentioned. From your code, I am guessing you were trying to use the icon-trigger built into the datepicker. I see two mistakes though:

1. You included the wrong URL for your image.
2. You displayed the image explicitly; datepicker takes care of that for you.

In summary, your code would look something like this:

```
    $( "#<%= this.txtFrom.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: "Images/clock_add.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showmonth:true,
        autoSize: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        duration: 'fast'
    });
```

And the ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" MaxLength="10" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter From Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks willam i need when the image button onlick event how to implement this?